# Which is least likely to crack due to high traffic, large or small tile?

Tags: tile, floor, remodeling

Consider a kitchen on pier-beam flooring with two doors allowing traffic to flow through it.
The floor is 10x10 feet. I plan to tile and would like to minimize risk of cracking.

Which size tile would be least likely to crack tile or grout, small tiles(2-4 inch sq) or large tiles (1x1ft)?

Comment: Good question- but the approach is incorrect! The answer is neither!  The question should be how to lay tiles so they don't crack! The floor need to be prepared correctly and fairly even and then You need a tiler that will properly lay tiles-with good adhesive spread and consistency. dry at the right speed and grout with an elastic based filler. Otherwise people wouldn't be selling large tiles if they cracked easier- don't you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smaller tiles are less likely to crack on the tile itself, the joints will give first.  But larger tiles are stronger in general.

That said, you should work on increasing the strength of your floor before tiling if you are concerned about cracking.  If you can access the joists, sister any weak places between two load bearing points.  On the floor itself, install a cement board with lots of screws along the joists.  Stagger any joints from the subfloor below.  And make sure the entire surface is perfectly flat (level is good, flat is required).